# How to tag user in Facebook post using Graph API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I did a research, and most of the topics are at least one year old. So, wondering is there a way to tag user in the Facebook wall post using Graph API?

Some relevant but not working solutions:
http://digitizor.com/2011/01/24/tag-user-facebook-graph/

FB documentation for the wallpost mentions message_tags field, which is "Objects tagged in the message (Users, Pages, etc)".
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

So is it possible somehow to add a tag in the wallpost to another user knowing its id?

Trying to implement this in the Rails application using Koala gem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @[id:name] way of tagging people inside of a post’s *text content* has been removed quite some time ago; it is only available to user actually posting through Facebook, not via API.

You *can* however tag people as “being with you” when making the post – but that requires a location as well, and as Gil already said should only be done if people were actually physically with you at the time of posting.

For details, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the case at the moment. Thanks :D

Comment: This should actually still be possible it's just split in action and mention tagging these days: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/mention-tagging/

Answer (score 1):

This still seems to be a bug with either facebook / koala. I couldn't get it to work using the @[id:name] style, and it doesn't look like there is another way to tag at the moment. Let me know if you figure something out!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to either tag or mention a user or page in Facebook posts within the current FB API.

Specifics on each of these can be found here.

**Mention a user or page in a Facebook post:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#mentions

**Tag a user or page in a Facebook post:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#tags

Answer (score 0):

If your wall post is better suited as an open graph action, you can certainly tag users that way. However, actions do require that the tagged people were actually involved in the activity at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of not exactly what I need, but seems to be the case. Thanks!